# Fetch Image with a POST request in Image src

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to fetch an image with a POST request. I'm following the docs at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#network-requests-for-images

But I don't know why it always sends a GET request with no body content. The request body is needed for my server to generate the image and it's too long to pass in the request params.

```xml
<Image
    source={{
        uri: 'https://bar-chart-api.herokuapp.com/plot.png',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Pragma: 'no-cache',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'image/png'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this._extractRoundsForChart(this.state.rounds)),
    }}
    style={{width: 400, height: 200}}
/>
```

Please help me with this, thanks!